# How to convert a magic square into a proper magic square in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

I have magic square like this. The digits in the magic square 3x3 can only be from 1-9:

```
magic_square = [[5,3,4],
                [1,5,8],
                [6,4,2]]
```

I want to convert it to a proper 3x3 magic square with all rows, columns and diagonals equal to the sum 15, with the most minimal changes possible.

I have tried with permutations but I can't figure out a way to do it.

Comment: I found this program which generates magic squares. It may be insightful. You could also reverse engineer it to create a program that solves magic squares. Good luck! https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/magic-square/

Comment: What have you tried with permutations? If you generate all permutations of the matrix, filter it on the ones that are magic squares, and then sort by how many changes it takes to get your input (I don't know how you're defining "changes" exactly), that will solve your problem. Not very efficiently, but for 3x3, that may be fine. If you're stuck on some part of that solution, that's fine; show us what you have and where you're stuck and we can get you unstuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear from the question what a "change" is, but this code assumes that it means replacing the value in one array location with a different value. An alternative meaning would be the number of swaps needed (which would need a little more code).

This code does the obvious thing: it generates all magic squares (of which there is only one up to reflections and rotations) and measures the distance to each, finding the smallest one.

```
import itertools

def ms():
    rows = [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [0, 3, 6], [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [0, 4, 8], [2, 4, 6]]

    for p in itertools.permutations(range(1, 10)):
        if all(sum(p[i] for i in r) == 15 for r in rows):
            yield list(p)

def closest_ms(m):
    m = sum(m, [])
    return min(ms(), key=(lambda x: sum(i!=j for i, j in zip(m, x))))

magic_square = [[5,3,4],
                [1,5,8],
                [6,4,2]]

print(closest_ms(magic_square))
```

The code returns the magic square with 6 elements in common with the original:

```
8 3 4
1 5 9
6 7 2
```